# How to use SqlTransaction to insert a master record and detail

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I'm trying to use SqlTransaction from C# to create a transaction that performs an insertion into a table called "maestro" and another table called "detalles". I have managed to insert without any issues, but I believe I am doing it wrong because I am passing the foreign key field to the details from the data layer, whereas I think I should pass the data from the presentation layer. However, I can't capture the auto-incremented value "MaestroId" at that moment to add it to my list.

I have the following code:

Data Layer:

```
public void registerMasterAndDetail(string name, List<EN_MasterDetail> masterDetails)
{
    BDConnection bdConnection = new BDConnection();
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = bdConnection.OpenConnection())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(connection.State.ToString());
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            // Output parameter to obtain the MaestroId
            SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@MaestroId", SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            int maestroId;

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertMaster", connection, transaction))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
                // Add output parameter
                command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

                // Execute the stored procedure
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Obtain the MaestroId from the output parameter
                maestroId = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);
            }

            foreach (var detail in masterDetails)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertDetail", connection, transaction))
                {
                    command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaestroId", maestroId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", detail.LastNames);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Logic Layer:

```
public void registerMasterAndDetail(string name, List<EN_MasterDetail> masterDetail)
{
    BD_MasterDetail bdMasterDetail = new BD_MasterDetail();
    bdMasterDetail.registerMasterAndDetail(name, masterDetail);
}
```

In the Presentation Layer, I'm struggling with how to obtain the value of the "MaestroId" field to send it to the detail. I have tried the following code, but I haven't been able to obtain that value:

```
public void Method1()
{
    RN_MasterDetail rnMasterDetail = new RN_MasterDetail();
    EN_MasterDetail masterDetail = new EN_MasterDetail
    {
        MaestroId = 1, // Here I need to obtain the value from the master table,
        LastNames = "Melgar",
        Age = 30, // Assume a value for the example
        Height = 1.75 // Assume a value for the example
    };
    rnMasterDetail.registerMasterAndDetail("Master 1", masterDetail);
}
```

As you can see, in this line, I am hardcoding the value of the "MaestroId" field. But only one data is saved for each last name, and I want one "MaestroId" to have several "Details". This is an example because in the program I'm trying to make, it should iterate through a dataGridView.

I have tried to change my methods to return a boolean, in the master so that if it is saved, the detail is saved only if the detail table exists. However, if the detail table does not exist, I would still have data inconsistency.

I have tried to add the value of the maestroId field directly from the Data layer, but I don't think that's what should be done. I have also tried to divide the methods, but I still don't know how to get the MaestroId value to pass it to the detail.

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaestroId", maestroId);

Comment: Can't you just `return maestroId;` in the `registerMasterAndDetail` function in the data layer, and then set it in to the property in the logic/business layer? Side note: Rather than using a `try catch Rollback()` for the transaction, you can just put it in a `using`. And showing message boxes from the data layer is not correct separation of concerns. (Quite why you'd need to show the connection state of a connection you just opened without error is another question)

Comment: Thank you for your comment regarding my problem, but my problem that is the one that makes me come to ask for collaboration is for the obtaining of the MaestroId field

I will post a possible solution, but I think it can be much better

thanks

Comment: You already have it on this line `maestroId = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);` you just need to pass it back out the function to set the relevant property.

Comment: Thank you very much for practically waiting for my comment, thank you very much, but it is precisely what I do not know how to do

I would appreciate it very much if you could show me an example

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does work for me, but I think there may be something that is more maintainable. I would like to register the kardex after registering the sale in the same transaction. Could you please comment on how a sales transaction works in a supermarket so that I can change my approach?

```
 public void registerMasterAndDetail(string name, List<EN_MasterDetail> masterDetails)
{
    BDConnection bdConnection = new BDConnection();
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = bdConnection.OpenConnection())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(connection.State.ToString());
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            // Output parameter to obtain the MaestroId
            SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@IdMaster", SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertMaster", connection, transaction))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
                // Add output parameter
                command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

                // Execute the stored procedure
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Obtain the MaestroId from the output parameter
                int maestroId = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);

                // Assign the MaestroId to each detail
                foreach (var detail in masterDetails)
                {
                    detail.MaestroId = maestroId;
                }

                // Now masterDetails list contains MaestroId for each detail

                // Insert details into the Detail table
                foreach (var detail in masterDetails)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand detailCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertDetail", connection, transaction))
                    {
                        detailCommand.CommandTimeout = 20;
                        detailCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        detailCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaestroId", detail.MaestroId);
                        detailCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", detail.LastName);

                        detailCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

And in this code in the presentation layer I have this code that works

```
    public void Method1()
{
    // Create a list of EN_MasterDetail objects
    List<EN_MasterDetail> masterDetails = new List<EN_MasterDetail>();

    // Fill the list with the last names you want
    // You can use the constructor of the EN_MasterDetail class or its properties
    masterDetails.Add(new EN_MasterDetail { LastName = "Pérez" });
    masterDetails.Add(new EN_MasterDetail { LastName = "García" });
    masterDetails.Add(new EN_MasterDetail { LastName = "López" });

    // Invoke the registerMasterAndDetail method passing the master name and the list of details
    BD_MasterDetail bdMasterDetail = new BD_MasterDetail();
    bdMasterDetail.registerMasterAndDetail("Master 1", masterDetails);

    // You don't need the MaestroId here; it is handled internally
}
```

I am writing this code because I believe it is the best way to control inconsistencies. After saving the sale, I have to save the Kardex, and that's why I need to obtain the MaestroId field.

Please, and if it doesn't violate the forum policies, provide the code you think I should have written to achieve what I needed.

I'm also providing the table structure in case you want to create a small project and test it without taking too much time:

```
 -- Create Maestro table
CREATE TABLE Maestro (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Create Detail table`enter code here`
CREATE TABLE Detail (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MaestroId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Maestro(Id),
    LastName VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

-- Create stored procedures to insert data
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertMaster
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @IdMaster INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Maestro (Nombre)
    VALUES (@Name);

    SET @IdMaster = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertDetail
    @MaestroId INT,
    @LastName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Detail (MaestroId, LastName)
    VALUES (@MaestroId, @LastName);
END;

SELECT * FROM Maestro;
SELECT * FROM Detail;

DELETE FROM Detail;
DELETE FROM Maestro;

DROP TABLE Detail -- To test if the rollback works
```

Please, based on what I have done, give me an example so I can continue with my work. Thank you.

Comment: That code looks correct, assuming you want to pass back the `MaestroID` within the object rather than separately (eg as a return value). Please put the table structure code in the question rather than the answer.

Comment: If you believe my answer is correct, should I accept it as an answer? Or is it not my place to do so?

Comment: You may accept your own answer, you can't upvote it though.

Comment: Then I will do it, and I will adapt this example to my code for a sales transaction. Then I will see how to add the entry of the sale to the kardex to the transaction.
thank